# How can I decrease the health of an item by 1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a mine craft bed-wars mini-game designed for 1v1v1v1. In your base there is an item spawner that occasionally spawns iron and gold. To limit the amount that spawns I am going to use the nbt: Health. I am going to have a clock going into a command block that decreases the heath of all gold and iron by 1. They will eventually go from 5 to 0 and DE-spawn. I have this command started but I don't know what to put next.

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:1}}] run data merge entity @s {}
```

I just need something to make the health decrease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's unfortunately no way of decreasing NBT tags with commands. You can only set them.

**You can however do this:**

The NBT tag `{Health:Xs}` acts just like hearts, and the item dies just like a normal player does when it hits 0. You can spawn the items on fire and set the health value to the amount of seconds you want the items to last.

*Example:*

```
summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"stone",Count:1b},Fire:1200s,Health:60s}
```

The item I just summoned with this command will last for 60 seconds total. The NBT tag `{Fire:Xs}` works with ticks. And fire takes 1 value off the Health NBT tag per second. Meaning the item will die in 60 seconds. **(1 second = 20 ticks)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dude @thaccoman10285 You are an absolute legend. Not only do the items disappear, THEY LOOK SICK AS FLIP!!! I have been trying so long to limit the number that spawn. I've tried scoreboards I've tried aging them up so they DE-spawn faster. (But they just clump up and it messes with their age.) Thanks for putting in the time to answer me. Means a lot.   EDIT: they still do clump up, I don't know what to do about that. Still works though, it just kill a lot then they build back up and it kills a lot of them again. Thanks again though.